# How to renew spotify session?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, session, spotify

I have an application that allow users to stream songs from spotify. So to achieve that I need to renew session from time to time whenever users want to stream song from spotify. I'm using latest spotify sdk (beta-9), and I'm currently following tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeO00YdJ3cE. In that tutorial we need to **refresh token swap** but when I looked from https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/ there is no need to refresh token swap.

and I end up not using the token swap, when I refresh my session then play song with renewed session, I got below error:

> Error Domain=com.spotify.ios-sdk.playback Code=8 "Login to Spotify failed because of invalid credentials." UserInfo=0x7f840bf807b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Login to Spotify failed because of invalid credentials.}

And I'm using this code below, for renewing my session:

```
 let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let sessionObj : AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("spotifySession") {

        let sessionDataObj : NSData = sessionObj as! NSData
        let session = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(sessionDataObj) as! SPTSession
        self.playUsingSession(session)

        if !session.isValid() {

            SPTAuth.defaultInstance().renewSession(session, callback: { (error : NSError!, newsession : SPTSession!) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                    let sessionData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(session)
                    userDefaults.setObject(sessionData, forKey: "spotifySession")
                    userDefaults.synchronize()

                    self.session = newsession

                    self.playUsingSession(newsession)

                }else{

                    println("renew session having problerm >>>>> \(error)")

                }
            })
        }else{

            println("session is still valid")
            self.playUsingSession(session)

        }

    }else{

        spotifyLoginButton.hidden = false

    }
```

and below code to stream spotify songs:

```
func playUsingSession(sessionObj:SPTSession!){

    if spotifyPlayer == nil {

        spotifyPlayer = SPTAudioStreamingController(clientId: kSpotifyClientID)

    }

    spotifyPlayer?.loginWithSession(sessionObj, callback: { (error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {

            println("enabling playback got error : \(error)")

            return

        }
        var spotifyTrackUri : NSURL = NSURL(string: "spotify:track:3FREWTEY2uFxOorJZMmZPX")!
        self.spotifyPlayer!.playURIs([spotifyTrackUri], fromIndex: 0, callback: { (error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {

                println("\(error)")

            }
        })

    })

}
```

Do I still need to refresh token swap for latest sdk? Or is there something missing with my code?

Answer (score 11):

By default, users need to login once per hour for apps using the Spotify SDK unless you use the Authorization Code flow. To use this flow you'll need to setup a server to handle token swap and refresh.

1. Setup a free server with this one-click-deploy to Heroku https://github.com/adamontherun/SpotifyTokenRefresh
2. Using the URL of the server created above add the following when configuring your SPTAuth.defaultInstance():

   SPTAuth.defaultInstance().tokenSwapURL = URL(string: "https://YOURSERVERNAME.herokuapp.com/swap")
           SPTAuth.defaultInstance().tokenRefreshURL = URL(string: "https://YOURSERVERNAME.herokuapp.com/refresh")
3. Before using your session check if it is valid:

   if SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session.isValid()

and if it isn't call

```
SPTAuth.defaultInstance().renewSession(SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session, callback: { (error, session) in
                        if let session = session {
                            SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session = session
                        } 
                    })
```

Comment: this is pretty awesome. thank you so much for that! but I'm receiving: `JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.` any idea?

Comment: `Using the URL of the server created above add the following when configuring your SPTAuth.defaultInstance():` can u plz explain more

Answer (score 0):

I recommend follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/@brianhans/getting-started-with-the-spotify-ios-sdk-435607216ecc and this one too: https://medium.com/@brianhans/spotify-ios-sdk-authentication-b2c35cd4affb

After you finished, you'll see that you create a file called "Constants.swift" just like this:

```
import Foundation

struct Constants {
  static let clientID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  static let redirectURI = URL(string: "yourappname://")!
  static let sessionKey = "spotifySessionKey"
}
```

Then, you can follow the steps in Heroku (Do not enter in panic is very simple):

https://github.com/adamontherun/SpotifyTokenRefresh

almost ready, when your server is "working", come back to your Xcode Project and add two static constants in your "Constants.swift" file, just like this:

```
import Foundation

struct Constants {
  static let clientID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  static let redirectURI = URL(string: "yourappname://")!
  static let sessionKey = "spotifySessionKey"
  static let tokenSawp = URL(string: "https://yourappname.herokuapp.com/swap")
  static let tokenRefresh = URL(string:"https://yourappname.herokuapp.com/refresh")
}
```

To finish, go to AppDelegate.swift and search "func setupSpotify()".. Add the new two constants, your function should look like this:

```
func setupSpotify() {
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().clientID = Constants.clientID
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().redirectURL = Constants.redirectURI
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().sessionUserDefaultsKey = Constants.sessionKey
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().tokenSwapURL = Constants.tokenSawp //new constant added
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().tokenRefreshURL = Constants.tokenRefresh //new constant added

    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().requestedScopes = [SPTAuthStreamingScope]

    do {
        try SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance().start(withClientId: Constants.clientID)


    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't start Spotify SDK")
    }
}
```

As a last step, just add the SPTAuth.defaultInstance().renewSession in you signInSpotify function, should look like this:

```
    @IBAction func SignInSpotify(_ sender: Any) {
    if SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session == nil {

        let appURL = SPTAuth.defaultInstance().spotifyAppAuthenticationURL()
        let webURL = SPTAuth.defaultInstance().spotifyWebAuthenticationURL()!

        // Before presenting the view controllers we are going to start watching for the notification
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(receievedUrlFromSpotify(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.Spotify.authURLOpened,
                                               object: nil)

        if SPTAuth.supportsApplicationAuthentication() {
            UIApplication.shared.open(appURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            let webVC = SFSafariViewController(url: webURL)
            present(webVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    } else if SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session.isValid() == true {
        print("YOUR SESSION IS VALID")
        self.successfulLogin()
    } else {
        print("YOUR SESSION IS NOT VALID / NEED RENEW")
        //Every 60 minutes the token need a renew https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk

        SPTAuth.defaultInstance().renewSession(SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session, callback: { (error, session) in
            if let session = session {
                SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session = session
                self.successfulLogin()
                print("RENEW OK")
            }

            if let error = error {
                print("RENEW NOT OK \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Good Luck!